# Como instalo módulos de Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

Estoy haciendo un programa y me gustaría convertirlo a un ejecutable en MacOS. Pensaba instalar cx_freeze, pero no se como instalarlo, mis preguntas son:

1. ¿De donde lo descargo?
2. ¿Cual descargo?(ya que he visto que hay source, wheel etc.)
3. ¿Como lo instalo? 
   -Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para instalar cx_freeze lo puedes hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
python3 -m pip install cx_Freeze --upgrade
```

Como dice en su documentación oficial: [cx_Freeze](https://anthony-tuininga.github.io/cx_Freeze/) permite trabajar con cualquier plataforma.

Cualquier programa siempre es mejor descargarlo de los repos oficiales, ya que siempre van a estar actualizados.

Saludos, espero haberte ayudado. ;)